# What does this integral notation $\int \Theta(t')dt'$ of $\Theta(t)$ mean?

Tags: integration, derivatives

What does it mean when a function of time $\Theta(t)$ is integrated but the notation looks like this:
$$\int \Theta(t')dt'$$
instead of the normal notation of just having $t$. What does the apostrophe here mean? Is it a time derivative/integral of some sort? Any leads to this is very much appreciated.

Comment: It means exactly the same as if you replace the t prime with a good ol' t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often used when you are integrating over a certain variable, time for example with some cut-off such :
$$ I(t) = \int_0^t \Theta(t') dt'$$
It allows the reader to understand that it is a local variable for the integration process.
There is no link with the derivation of the variable, it just gives the information that it is an integration variable.